# How to change dir property of the Angular CDK overlay at runtime?

Tags: html, angular, dom, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I'm using Angular 10, on click the following function is executed to preform direction change:

```
private changeHtmlDirection(direction: 'rtl' | 'ltr') {
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].dir = direction;
}
```

It works well, only that the Angular CDK does not update.

I tried to find an API to change Angular CDK's direction at runtime, but couldn't find any.
I saw that there's a [BidiModule](https://material.angular.io/cdk/bidi/overview) but it uses only to get the current direction rather than set it.

Is there any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the material documentation, you can't change 'dir' on the "html" tag so that affects bidi API. You can see the document at the following link:
[bi-directionality document](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/guides/bidirectionality.md)

But if you want to use material bi-directionality you can add the 'dir' directive to a container element in the root component like bellow:

```
<div [dir]="documentDirection"> </div>
```

and whenever the 'documentDirection' variable changes, the bidi "change emitter" will be emit.
like following code you can subscribe to it:

```
constructor(
private dir: Directionality ) {
this.isRtl = dir.value === 'rtl';
 this.dir.change.subscribe(() => {
  this.isRtl = !this.isRtl;
 });
```

}